# Editing the default table created by simpleMembership system

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am learning through the MVC4 default project files.

I am trying to add a new column into the default UserProfile table but it doesn't work for me. The column is added on the editor but I can only save the table as another .sql script extension file.

Therefore I follow this article

http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/

and added a property
`public string UserEmail(){get;set;}` into the UserProfile class

Then I rerun `"update-database -verbose"` 
But I get the error

> There is already an object named 'UserProfile' in the database.

Answer (score 1):

With Entity Framework 5 and Database Migration, every time you add a property to the model in your case `Model being UserProfile` and you added `public string UserEmail(){ get; set; }` you have to excute `Update-Database -Force` in Package Manager Console to update your database or you will get that error you mentioned above. Also make sure that the right project is sellected while you do this. And while you are at it, in your `Configuaration.cs` set `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;` This is good during development but set it to false once you are about to deploy to production.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the Default Userprofile is still in AccountsModels.cs (in Models dir), and having 2 classes with the same name is not allowed. do a CTRL F for "class UserProfile", if you don t find 2 then try to add the -Force flag.

Comment: oh thanks but no, it is not like that. I didn't add any more UserProfile class in the model file.

Comment: or in some other class, or you perhaps got 2 ASP.net MVC projects ? (then there will be 2 UserProfile classes in each project 1.